# void loop runs no effect

Tags: apex, unit-test, loop, method

I am attempting to write a simple test for a for loop that cleans the websites fields of unwanted elements such as 'http', 'www' etc. The script works for me but the test class that I wrote gets me 0% of coverage. Could anyone advise on what I am doing wrong?

```
public class standardiseWebsites {

public void standardiseWebsites(){
//extracting the host from the address for websites that have web-protocol (http:// and https://)
list<Account> accts = [SELECT Website FROM Account WHERE Website LIKE 'http://%' OR Website LIKE 'https://%'];
    for (Account acct : accts){            
        string website = acct.Website;
        Url u = new Url(acct.Website);
        acct.Website = u.getHost();
        update acct;
    }

  //removing first 4 digits of the address if it starts with 'www.' (non-web-protocol values)
  list<Account> accts2 = [SELECT Website FROM Account WHERE Website LIKE 'www.%'];
    for (Account acct2 : accts2){
        string website = acct2.website;
        website = website.substring(4);
        acct2.website = website;
        update acct2;
    }
}
}
```

And the test for it:

```
@isTest
public class standardiseWebsitesTest {
    static testMethod void standardiseWebsitesTest(){

        //Run the test
        standardiseWebsites ca = new standardiseWebsites();
        ca.standardiseWebsites();

    }
}
```

Nitish, thank you. I created the following class:

```
public class standardiseWebsites {

public standardiseWebsites(){
//extracting the host from the address for websites that have web-protocol (http:// and https://)
list<Account> accts = [SELECT Website FROM Account WHERE Website LIKE 'http://%' OR Website LIKE 'https://%'];
    for (Account acct : accts){            
        string website = acct.Website;
        Url u = new Url(acct.Website);
        acct.Website = u.getHost();
        update acct;
    }

  //removing first 4 digits of the address if it starts with 'www.' (non-web-protocol values)
  list<Account> accts2 = [SELECT Website FROM Account WHERE Website LIKE 'www.%'];
    for (Account acct2 : accts2){
        string website = acct2.website;
        website = website.substring(4);
        acct2.website = website;
        update acct2;
    }
}
```

}

But when trying to save I receive an error:

Line 10, Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [standardiseWebsites].standardiseWebsites()

Just to remind the method I am using is not void.

Comment: Do *not* remove "www" from URLs. Many websites will not operate correctly without it.

Comment: Please merge your accounts by using the [contact us](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) link which displays on every page. Note that your most recent error is because you did not declare the method static, nor give it a return type. You might want to work through some Trailhead modules to get a better handle on syntax.

Comment: In your original class, please use void keyword, just before the method name, similar to what you did originally. 

public class standardiseWebsites {

public void standardiseWebsites(){

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the actual methods for testing in your test class, you need to create test data. I would suggest you go through the below link once, where it clearly shows how to write the methods in test class which help create the test data.

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/testsetup-method-in-apex-test-classes/

```
//Below is a method with @testsetup annotation, the name can be anything like setup(), oneTimeData(), etc.
@testSetup static void setup() {
    // Create common test accounts
    List<Account> testAccts = new List<Account>();
    testAccts.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAcct1', website='www.google.com'));
    testAccts.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAcct2',website='http://www.google.com'));
    insert testAccts;
}
@isTest public class standardiseWebsitesTest{ 
   static testMethod void standardiseWebsitesTest(){
     //Run the test
       standardiseWebsites ca = new standardiseWebsites();
       ca.standardiseWebsites();
  }
 }
```

please test by introducing a setup method in your test class, as shown above.

Comment: Nitish, thank you for this but when running your script I get an error on line 2: unexpected token 'void'. Also as you will notice my method isn't void. When I change the actual script method to void it runs but the websites aren't changed (no effect).

Comment: I have given you the test class script, and data insertion in setup method, and changes in testMethod will be reverted, and they will not be visible in the org. If you are getting code coverage 100%, then you may just need to include some assert statements in your testmethod code at the end. Please refer to the link for more understanding. http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/testsetup-method-in-apex-test-classes/

Comment: Ok, how do you test your actual class code working or not? Using developer console? because when you don't use void, the method is a constructor and it gets called as soon as instance of class is created. If you use void, you have to explicitly call the method using instance of the class.